# PowerBI, DAX. Is there a way to set an upper limit to a slicer?

Tags: date, powerbi, dax, slicers

I'm trying to create some measures using DAX on an underlying data model which I would then use for creating some visuals (line chart, bar chart etc.). Each table in the data model has a data field (date&time) that contains repeated dates and times (more occurencies with the same date&time). To use the metrics in the visuals I need the measures to be grouped for date (only date, not for time).

To achieve the task I've created a calendar table (using CALENDAR in DAX) to set-up a set of dates (only dates) to which refer at for every table in the data model and created relations (dates that points to calendar date) for every table. I set the upper limit of the calendar table to be a year ahead of the max date in the dataset, because some measures need to be evaluated in the future.

In the visual pages, I put a slicer that points to the calendar table dates, but the date interval is too wide. I need the slicer to have a more narrow interval, let's say, only "for the present and the past" but I prefer not to add another calculated table.

In your opinion, is there a way to limit the slicer without changing its reference to the calendar table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the calendar you may just use CALENDARAUTO(). It will expand automatically as the data model expands.

For the slicer, just select it, open the filter pane and define a filter with the upper limit you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of 3 different slicer for your purpose. This is just another option that you can have a look on. There will be 3 slicer for Year, Month & Date. So Date slicer is you final slicer, with 2 other slicer on top of it to generate necessary Dates in the slicer. This way, you are not making any static restriction to generate the Date list but giving the user full control on the Date range. Here below is a sample how the slicers can be look in practical.

[image]

User can select any year or multiple year, any month or multiple month. Finally the date slicer will hold Date values accordingly.